# Gravity only working after a keystoke AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, gravity

Here is my problem, I am new to programming and I am following a tutorial just to learn random things. I have gotten everything to work so far except gravity. When I run the program my player is floating, but when I hit the "down" key only then the gravity takes effect.. I can't figure out why.

```
if(leftBumping){
    if(xSpeed < 0){
        xSpeed *= -0.5;
    }
}

if(rightBumping){
    if(xSpeed > 0){
        xSpeed *= -0.5;
    }
}

if(upBumping){
    if(ySpeed < 0){
        ySpeed *= -0.5;
    }
}

if(downBumping){
    if(ySpeed > 0){
        ySpeed *= 0.0;
    }




} 
else {
        ySpeed += gravityConstant;
}
```

I have a trace on the bumping collisions and they all work properly. If i am in open space it detect no collision, and when touching walls the output shows i am. Iv been reworking these lines for hours. PLease help

this may help also

```
if(aPressed){
    xSpeed -= speedConstant;

} else if (dPressed){
    xSpeed += speedConstant;

}

if (wPressed){
    ySpeed -= speedConstant;

} else if(sPressed){
    ySpeed += speedConstant;
}
if(leftBumping){
    if(xSpeed < 0){
        xSpeed *= -0.5;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful to have a little more context. Where do you specify responses to different keys?

Comment: Thats almost my whole program. I can post the whole thing, just didn't know if i needed to

Comment: How is downBumping been set?

Answer (score 0):

You need to stick this bit:

```
ySpeed += gravityConstant;
```

into a function that is called every frame, like this:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame)

private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
{
    ySpeed += gravityConstant;
}
```

if this is happening to quickly, you will either need to reduce your gravity constant, reduce the fps, or use a timer rather than enterframe.